# How can I get multiple columns values into single row in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

My exact requirement is that if the output of the query `'select amount, quantity from temp_table where type = 5;'` is:

```
amount | quantity

10     |  5

20     |  7

12     |  10
```

Then, the output should be displayed as:

```
amount1 | amount2 | amount3 | quantity1 | quantity2 | quantity3

10      |  20     |  12     |  5        |  7        |   10
```

Comment: Can you give us more data?  What happens if you have 20 records in the original table?

Comment: its very unlikely. max rows can be 10.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(amount, '|') WITHIN GROUP (order by amount) 
|| LISTAGG(quantity, '|')  WITHIN GROUP (order by amount) as result
FROM temp_table where type = 5;
```

*Have in mind, that the values of the columns amount and quantity are separated by spaces, thus the ' ' in the [listagg()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) expression. You can change it to '|' or anything else if you like.

Cheers

Comment: I think there is slight misunderstanding. The pipe '|', in the description, is not used as a delimiter, but to denote a different column. Amount1, Amount2...  should be different columns whose values should be 10, 20 and so on..

Comment: I changed my answer to include '|' as a delimiter. As I mentioned - you can put any `string` in place of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT "1_AMOUNT" AS Amount1,
       "2_AMOUNT" AS Amount2,
       "3_AMOUNT" AS Amount3,
       "4_AMOUNT" AS Amount4,
       "5_AMOUNT" AS Amount5,
       "1_QUANTITY" AS Quantity1,
       "2_QUANTITY" AS Quantity2,
       "3_QUANTITY" AS Quantity3,
       "4_QUANTITY" AS Quantity4,
       "5_QUANTITY" AS Quantity5
FROM   ( SELECT amount, quantity, ROWNUM rn FROM temp_table WHERE type = 5 )
PIVOT  ( MAX( amount ) AS amount,
         MAX( quantity ) AS quantity
         FOR rn IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) );
```